# Determining the value of an active. cell.value

Tags: uitableview, excel, vba

I am working on a simple checkbook spreadsheet.  When I attempt t balance the book, I end up by entering the balance from the statement in column I.  Column F contains my Balance forward, column H contains a correction  number, made up of all transaction amounts not returned yet, and column J contains a formula to add the contents of the relevant cell in columns H and I and subtract the contents of the relevant cell in column F.  If everything has been input correctly, the relevant cell in column J appears as $0.00 (cell is formatted as currency).

My script then checks to see if everything was input correctly or not. It activates the relevant cell in column J and 'If ActiveCell.Value = 0' it flags everything as correct. On the following line in the script, 'If ActiveCell.Value <> 0' the script checks to see if the value is positive or negative and flags it appropriately.

For some reason, when I've input all my transactions correctly, the script does not see the cell value (which appears as $0.00 to the eye) as = 0.  instead it flags it as a negative value.

I am confused.  I am also using Excel 2013 and VBA scripting

Comment: What you see is the formatted value. Check what is the underlying value. You can see that in the formula bar.

Answer (score 1):

You are seeing round-off error which is too small to be displayed using the default precision. Here is a simple example:

```
Sub test1()
    Dim num As Double, total As Double
    Dim i As Long

    num = 0.1
    For i = 1 To 10
        total = total + num
    Next i
    MsgBox total
    total = 1 - total 'should be 0, no?
    If total > 0 Then
        MsgBox "Negative"
    ElseIf total = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Balanced"
    Else
        MsgBox "Positive"
    End If
End Sub
```

"Negative" pops up. The problem is that the real number 0.1 *when written in base 2* has a repeating decimal expansion (sort of like 2/3 in base 10) which is rounded (sort of like how we round 2/3 to 0.666667) hence the number that the computer uses is actually a bit *larger* than 0.1 hence 10 of them together sums not to 1.0 but to something more like 1.00000000001, hence when you subtract it from 1, instead of balancing you get a small negative number.

There are various solutions. One of the easiest is to declare all of your variables which hold financial data to be `Variant` and then use `CDec` to initialize them. This converts it to the Variant subtype Decimal which doesn't have the same problem. (Unfortunately you can't declare a variable as decimal directly). For example:

```
Sub test2()
    Dim num As Variant, total As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    num = CDec(0)
    total = CDec(0)

    num = 0.1
    For i = 1 To 10
        total = total + num
    Next i
    MsgBox total
    total = 1 - total 'should be 0, no?
    If total > 0 Then
        MsgBox "Negative"
    ElseIf total = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Balanced"
    Else
        MsgBox "Positive"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I was thinking that it might be a rounding error, although I couldn't figure out where the very small amount was coming from.  I believe I can simply change my criteria.  Instead of =0, it is correct, or <> 0 and then check for positive or negative, I can  'If <1 AND >-1' it is correct, treat it as a 0, else check for positive or negative.

Comment: If your variables are for money -- you really should use the decimal type. Why *deal* with the resulting round-off error when you can *avoid* it? The following link is relevant (even though it is discussing VB.net rather than VBA) : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/xkd5z2s9(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Though I should add the qualification that decimal variables are not magic. They will have no round-off error at all for the operations needed to balance a checkbook. But, If you do things involving compound interest then the formulas involve exponentiation and unavoidably involve rounding. Nevertheless, even then the phenomenal precision of the decimal type minimizes the problem.

Comment: I appreciate the assistance.  I'm nowhere near compound interest or exponentiation. : )  Still,  I will give the decimal variables a try.  Thanks again.